# Understanding "Leading/Lagging" and "Phase Shifting" with Sinusoidal Functions?!

Tags: ac

INTRODUCTION/QUESTIONS:

I'm reading through a chapter on sinusoidal alternating waveforms and I'm having some difficulty in the section on Phase Relations. The generic expression is mentioned below for a waveform that has been shifted. Following that I posted a list of expressions that show their geometric relationship. Can someone explain the list of expressions in your own context or understanding.

I do not understand these angles and/or functions. Their meaning as well as their context in phase shifting is confusing to me. I need a better foundation of understanding to have a better intuitive approach towards problem solving. I've had Calculus 1 and I'm currently taking Calculus 2. Therefore, I'm familiar with trig functions but I just can't bring it all together.

I would of posted this in the mathematics forum. However, I felt receiving guidance/direction from an engineers point of view may be more beneficial.

[image: Expressions]

Answer (score 2):

You could think of leading and lagging as to whether a sinusoidal signal has a head start with respect to a reference wave, this would be the simplest way I could think of describing it. When you look at a cosine and sine wave the cosine leads by 90 degrees because, for this example cos(0)=1 while sin(0)=0. sine will not reach a value of 1 until a 1/4 of the cycle has occurred which is 90 degrees (360/4).

Has this helped?

Comment: Here is a problem that I'm not understanding. What is the phase relationship between the sinusoidal waveforms.    i=-2cos(wt-60)     v=3sin(wt-150)         These problems are really what's bringing on the confusion. I think i'm suppose to use those realationships above to somehow convert the expression that is not represented in sin form to sin form? Is this right. The answer to this question just for your reference is v and i are in phase. In there solution they converted the i expression to 2cos(wt-60-180)=2cos(wt-240). Can you explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

## Difference Between Sine and Cosine

The thing to remember is that sine and cosine are always shifted 90 degrees apart so that

cos(0) = 1 and sin(90) = 1

If you shift them both by 30 degrees it they will still have the same value:

cos(0+30) = sqrt(3)/2 and sin(90+30) = sqrt(3)/2

## Leading vs. Lagging

Leading and lagging don't really start becoming important until you have a time reference, which is where the omega * t term starts becoming important. The omega * t term can be thought of as your current phase, and the theta can be thought of as your starting phase.

If you take a measurement of two 2Hz sinusoids at time t = 0 and you get a value of sqrt(3)/2 for one and a value of 1/2 for the other then you know the second one is leading the first by 30 degrees, or conversely the first is lagging the second by 30 degrees:

cos(2*0 + 60) = sqrt(3)/2

cos(2*0 + 30) = 1/2

## Final Notes

- Get very familiar with the unit circle, it helps immensely when you start getting the hang of this stuff this stuff. Positive angle movements around the circle go counter clockwise, and negative go clockwise. X values are equivalent to the cos of the angle that a line makes from the center to different points on the circle. Y values are equivalent to the sin of the same angle.
- Remember that phase and frequency * time are equivalent

Comment: cos(60) is leading by 30 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following diagram from Wiki:

[image]

The x coordinate *cos t* and the y coordinate is *sin t* (the *t* in this diagram is the angle variable equivalent to the \$\theta\$ and \$\alpha\$ in your formulas).

Now consider points on the circle that are 90 degrees (and then 180 degrees etc.) clockwise or counter clockwise round the circle from the given point.  If you think carefully about it (draw some diagrams yourself) you'll be able to "see" the formulas given in your question.